# Count the absolute number and the percentage of NAs for every column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I want to create a new dataframe based on this with 3 columns. The first will be named `"Field"` and will contain the column names of this dataframe (`col1,col2,col3`). The second will be named `"Absolute"` and will contain the absolute number of missing values of this column and the third will be named `Percentage` and will contain the percentage of the missing values of this column. The number of columns and rows in my real dataframe is bigger.

```
col1<-c("as","df",NA)
col2<-c("ds",NA,NA)
col3<-c(NA,NA,NA)
df<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
data.frame(field = names(df), 
           Absolute = colSums(is.na(df)), 
           Percentage = 100 * (colSums(is.na(df)) / nrow(df)),
           row.names = seq(nrow(df)))

     field Absolute Percentage
   1  col1        1   33.33333
   2  col2        2   66.66667
   3  col3        3  100.00000
```

Comment: how can we include in this cells that are empty?

Comment: What do you mean? which cells?

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse approach (though I prefer @Sotos’ solution):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  summarize(across(
    everything(),
    list(
      Absolute = ~ sum(is.na(.x)), 
      Percentage = ~ mean(is.na(.x)) * 100
    )
  )) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c("Field", ".value"),
    names_sep = "_"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Field Absolute Percentage
  <chr>    <int>      <dbl>
1 col1         1       33.3
2 col2         2       66.7
3 col3         3      100
```